# Is physical energy is invariant under reflection?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, gauge-invariance, molecules, invariants

I am wondering whether the energy landscape of a physical system (in particular a molecular conformation) can be considered invariant under reflection of the 3D space. My understanding is that some factors, related for example to electron spin, might break this symmetry, is this correct? If so, how strong of an influence would this have on the atoms relative positions in a molecule.

Comment: If the individual molecules are not themselves chiral then the only aspect of physics able to break this symmetry is the weak force. This is a tiny force compared to electromagnetic (at ordinary scales of energy) so the influence on positions in a molecule is tiny and hence negligible in practice. But this is a comment not an answer since I don't have anything more quantitative to hand.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know where I could find an estimate of the relative strength of the two for this context?

Comment: see the value of the fundamental constants , the electromagnetic is the constant for the molecular state, the weak is the weak force http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/couple.html